# Regex tool on Windows

Tags: regex, windows

Need to work a bit on a pretty big text file.

Could someone suggest something similar to "The Regex Coach" but to be able to save matched results only?

Comment: What do you want to save them to?  Text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many good tools available.  I regularly use the following. Based on the OP, it sounds like a simple use of grep would work (`grep pattern file > newfile`).

- [grep](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm)
- [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)
- [awk](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm)
- [Ruby](http://rubyinstaller.org/)

Many others as well (Perl, Python, etc.)

Comment: @Mike:  I don't think you are correct.  I just downloaded and ran the setup for grep.  It only installed the files for grep.  It did not install all of cygwin (unless cygwin only consists of grep :)

Comment: Ugg I meant to say that your links are correct.  You have to go into the cygwin package selection utility and select the tools like awk and sed

Comment: Guess i'll go with Ruby. There is nice oneclick setup. Read a bit of documentations and write a small script. Thanks ;)

Comment: You don't need cygwin. Just add grep install location to your system PATH variable and use it from CMD.exe.

Answer (score 1):

Tools like "The Regex Coach" or the "[Regular Expression Designer](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/)" are tools to test regular expressions and not to work on files. I don't know one that can store the results, Regex Designer can store the Regexes in a xml file.

If you want to do that you should use a Editor with regular expression support, like:

- [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), is free but the regex support is a bit limited.
- [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/downloads/ultraedit_download.html), not free (trial period of 30 days), but better regex support

Answer (score 0):

[Regex Pixie](http://www.regexpixie.com) is a tool that can save just the matches.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Ultrapico's Expresso, which is a free desktop Windows app.  It allows complete development and testing of all scenarios specified in the IEEE specifications, and is a great tool.  I can't recommend it strongly enough.  It lets you save and retrieve projects, so if you are heavy into RegEx, you will be very happy with how it supports your needs.

https://regex101.com/ is available online, it's OK but nowhere near as robust as Expresso.

For Mac, there is [Re/g in the App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/regex-regular-expression-tester/id422501241?mt=12) for $13.99, I don't know how good it is.

For Linux, you can [run some quick checks in Bash shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112707/check-if-a-string-matches-a-regex-in-bash-script), but for playing around you are probably better off on the websites.