# Check if a string matches a regex in Bash script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, scripting

One of the arguments that my script receives is a date in the following format: `yyyymmdd`.

I want to check if I get a valid date as an input.

How can I do this? I am trying to use a regex like: `[0-9]\{\8}`

Comment: Checking if the format is right is easy. But i don't think that you can, in bash (with built-ins), check if the date is valid.

Answer (score 585, accepted):

You can use the test construct, `[[ ]]`, along with the regular expression match operator, `=~`, to check if a string matches a regex pattern ([documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-_005b_005b)).

For your specific case, you can write:

```
[[ "$date" =~ ^[0-9]{8}$ ]] && echo "yes"
```

Or more a accurate test:

```
[[ "$date" =~ ^[0-9]{4}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$ ]] && echo "yes"
#             |\______/\______*______/\______*__________*______/|
#             |   |           |                  |              |
#             |   |           |                  |              |
#             | --year--   --month--           --day--          |
#             |          either 01...09      either 01..09      |
#      start of line         or 10,11,12         or 10..29      |
#                                                or 30, 31      |
#                                                          end of line
```

That is, you can define a regex in *Bash* matching the format you want. This way you can do:

```
[[ "$date" =~ ^regex$ ]] && echo "matched" || echo "did not match"
```

where commands after `&&` are executed if the test is successful, and commands after `||` are executed if the test is unsuccessful.

Note this is based on the solution by Aleks-Daniel Jakimenko in [User input date format verification in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18748968/1983854).

---

In other shells you can use **grep**. If your shell is POSIX compliant, do

```
(echo "$date" | grep -Eq  ^regex$) && echo "matched" || echo "did not match"
```

In [fish](https://fishshell.com/), which is not POSIX-compliant, you can do

```
echo "$date" | grep -Eq "^regex\$"; and echo "matched"; or echo "did not match"
```

**Caveat:** These portable grep solutions are **not water-proof!** For example, they can be tricked by input parameters that contain newlines. The first mentioned bash-specific regex check does not have this issue.

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko using grep seems to be the best option if you’re using `sh`, `fish` or other less equipped shells.

Comment: @tomekwi, yes, of course. But this question is tagged [tag:bash], so it is better to give an answer that makes sense in bash. You can always list alternative sh-compatible solutions, but in no way it should be the main answer.

Comment: @fedorqui This regular expression allows month or/and day to be zero. For example these invalid dates are considered as valid by the code: 20160015 20161200 . I think the following patter is more accurate ^[0-9]{4}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$

Comment: Easy to understand code is always preferable to "good" code. This has been studied at length.

Comment: -1: I think I found a fatal problem with this approach (using `=~`): any string will  incorrectly match an empty string. For example `[[ a =~ "$badvar" ]]; echo $?` gives (incorrectly) 0, while `expr match "a" "$badvar" >/dev/null ; echo $?` gives correct result 1.

Comment: @PengheGeng my answer is about using regex to compare strings, while you are focusing on the `=~` operator. Also, note I am using the var on the left hand side of the expression.

Comment: The syntax suggested for `fish` does not work in fish. You need to write `cmd1; and cmd2` instead of `cmd1 && cmd2`. While your solution should still be POSIX-compliant, fish isn't, and you might want to indicate this.

Comment: @Qw3ry I do not have Fish here with me, would you mind clicking [edit] to suggest improvements? I will gladly approve those. Thanks!

Comment: `=~` would not help me match with `"[^:]+", so using `grep` now.

Comment: Caveat: this regex is not "smart" about dates -- `20190230` is considered perfectly valid by this regex, despite there never being a 30st day of February. Similarly it will accept the 31st on any month that actually only has 30 days, e.g. `20190431`.

Comment: Caveat: the solution using `grep` accepts multi-line values where each line contains a date: e.g. `printf '%s\n%s\n' "$date" "$date" | grep …` will be accepted which might not be expected.

Comment: wow! it never occured to me that I could use the batch operator (`&&`, I call it that because it turns the l and r values into an atomic batch) like this. It is a bit less readable than an if statement, but it is so space efficient that it is often worth the tradeoff, in my opinion. Thank you.

Comment: @NateT it is useful for ternary expressions --> `echo 1 && echo 2 || echo 3`

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' yeah, it is. I got so worked up over the 'and / if' that I don't even  think I made it to the tenary. I wonder if modern ternary expression syntax evolve from this. (i.e. `a  &&  b ||  c` =>  `a : b  ?  c` )

Comment: Is there a way to do the check with `sed`? That would be useful is one is going to check for a pattern, say `{(.+)}`, and if applicable do some substitution (say `\1`), because grep and sed have slightly different conventions.

Comment: @Erwann mmm could you provide an example?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' one can do `$ echo '{x}' | grep -E '{.}'; echo "$?"` to determine if there was a match. OTOH `echo '{x}' | sed -E 's/\{(.)\}/\1/'; echo "$?"` return `0` whether there is a match or not (such as by replacing `{x}` by `{x`). The way I deal with this is `if [[ $lhs =~ $pattern ]]; then echo "$lhs" | sed -E "s/$pattern/\1/"; else exit 1; fi`

Comment: please fix the grep solution to `printf '%s' "$input" | tr $'\n' ' ' | grep -q -E '^...$'`. i use `tr $'\n' ' '` to replace every newline with an illegal character. here i assume that space is an illegal character

Comment: Just add one example: `if [[ $(type dircolors) =~ ^dircolors\ is\ .* ]]; then  echo "Yes"; else  echo "No"; fi`

Answer (score 87):

In bash version 3 you can use the '=~' operator:

```
if [[ "$date" =~ ^[0-9]{8}$ ]]; then
    echo "Valid date"
else
    echo "Invalid date"
fi
```

Reference: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver3.html#REGEXMATCHREF

> NOTE: The quoting in the matching operator within the double brackets, [[ ]], is no longer necessary as of Bash version 3.2

Comment: This doesn't work. `if ! [[ "hello world" =~ 'hello [a-z]+' ]]; then echo "doesn't work"; f` prints "doesn't work". I tried with double quotes as well and that didn't help. Removing the quotes throws a syntax error (which is expected since there's a space).

Answer (score 46):

A good way to test if a string is a correct date is to use the command date:

```
if date -d "${DATE}" >/dev/null 2>&1
then
  # do what you need to do with your date
else
  echo "${DATE} incorrect date" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

from comment: one can use formatting

```
if [ "2017-01-14" == $(date -d "2017-01-14" '+%Y-%m-%d') ]
```

Comment: Highly rate your answer as it lets the date function deal with the dates and not the error-prone regexs'

Comment: This is good for checking on broad date options, but if you need to verify a specific date format, can it do that? For example if i do `date -d 2017-11-14e` it returns Tue Nov 14 05:00:00 UTC 2017, but that would break my script.

Comment: You could use something like that : if [ "2017-01-14" == $(date -d "2017-01-14" '+%Y-%m-%d') ]

It tests if the date is correct and check if the result is the same as your entered data.

By the way, be very careful with localized date format (Month-Day-Year vs. Day-Month-Year for instance)

Comment: Might not work, depending on your locale. American-formatted dates using MM-DD-YYYY won't work anywhere else in the world, using either DD-MM-YYYY (Europe) or YYYY-MM-DD (some places in Asia)

Comment: @Paul, what may not work? As written in a comment, one can use formatting options...

Comment: @Betlista, for example this fails, for today's date here in Belgium: date -d "12-01-2021" '+%d-%m-%Y', with "date: invalid date"

Comment: @Paul I confirm that, very strange on `date +%d-%m-%Y` I got `12-01-2021`, but conversion from string is not working here in Prague, good for new question

Answer (score 6):

In addition to other answers of the `=~` Bash operator - [Extended Regular Expressions (ERE)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/RegularExpression).

> This is the syntax used by `awk` and `egrep` (or `grep -E`),
> as well as by Bash's `[[ ... =~ ... ]]` operator.

For example, a function which supports multiple test provided in multiple arguments:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

#-----------#
# Functions #
#-----------#

function RT
{
    declare __line;

    for __line in "${@:2}";
    do
        if ! [[ "$__line" =~ $1 ]];
        then
            return 1;
        fi
    done

    return 0;
}

#-----------#
# Main      #
#-----------#

regex_v='^[0-9]*$';
value_1_v='12345';
value_2_v='67890';

if RT "$regex_v" "$value_1_v" "$value_2_v";
then
    printf 'Valid';
else
    printf 'Invalid';
fi
```

---

## Description

### Function `RT` or `Regex Test`

```bash
# Declare a local variable for a loop.

declare __line;
```

```bash
# Loop for every argument's value except the first - regex rule

for __line in "${@:2}";
```

```bash
# Test the value and return a **non-zero** return code if failed.
# Alternative: if [[ ! "$__line" =~ $1 ]];

if ! [[ "$__line" =~ $1 ]];
```

```bash
# Return a **zero** return code - success.

return 0;
```

### Main code

```bash
# Define arguments for the function to test

regex_v='^[0-9]*$'; # Regex rule
value_1_v='12345'; # First value
value_2_v='67890'; # Second value
```

```bash
# A statement which runs the function with specified arguments
# and executes `printf 'Valid';` if succeeded, else - `printf 'Invalid';`

if RT "$regex_v" "$value_v";
```

It should be possible to point at failed argument, for example, by appending a counter to the loop and printing its value to `stderr`.

## Related

> The **quotes** around the right-hand side of the `=~` operator cause it to become **a string**, rather than a [RegularExpression](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/RegularExpression).
>
> [Source](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5B.5B_.24foo_.3D.2BAH4_.27some_RE.27_.5D.5D)

Answer (score 1):

Where the usage of a regex can be helpful to determine if the character sequence of a date is correct, it cannot be used easily to determine if the date is valid. The following examples will pass the regular expression, but are all invalid dates: 20180231, 20190229, 20190431

So if you want to validate if your date string (let's call it `datestr`) is in the correct format, it is best to parse it with `date` and ask `date` to convert the string to the correct format. If both strings are identical, you have a valid format and valid date.

```
if [[ "$datestr" == $(date -d "$datestr" "+%Y%m%d" 2>/dev/null) ]]; then
     echo "Valid date"
else
     echo "Invalid date"
fi
```