# Bash and replacing the whole string in variable?

Tags: regex, bash, variables, replace

I'm trying to use Bash replacement to replace the whole string in variable if it matches a pattern. For example:

```
pattern="ABCD"

${var/pattern/}
```

removes (replaces with nothing) the first occurrence of `$pattern` in `$var`

```
${var#pattern}
```

removes `$pattern` in the beginning of `$var`

But how can I remove regex pattern `"^ABCD$"` from `$var`? I could:

```
if [ $var == "ABCD" ] ; then 
  echo "This is a match." # or whatever replacement
fi
```

but that's quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: What's wrong with `"${var/$pattern/}"`? Can you clarify with some example inputs.

Comment: @anubhava He's looking for a fully anchored replacement. That finds a match anywhere.

Comment: I can't think of anything materially better than that `if` statement. `[ "$var" = ABCD ] && var=""` is slightly more terse but the same idea.

Comment: @etan and @ fedorgui it works for me. Out of curiosity I'm going to leave this open for a while to see if there are other solutions. Thanks guys.

Comment: Note that your first two examples do NOT modify `$var` -- they expand to a string that comes from `$var` and has the corresponding change, but `$var` itself remains unchanged -- later instances of `$var` will not be affected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a regular expression check:

```
pattern="^ABCD$"
[[ "$var" =~ $pattern ]] && var=""
```

it checks `$var` with the regular expression defined in `$pattern`. In case it matches, it performs the command `var=""`.

#### Test

```
$ pattern="^ABCD$"
$ var="ABCD"
$ [[ "$var" =~ $pattern ]] && echo "yes"
yes
$ var="1ABCD"
$ [[ "$var" =~ $pattern ]] && echo "yes"
$
```

See [check if string match a regex in BASH Shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21112809/1983854) for more info.