# if condition in Linux

Tags: regex, bash, shell, if-statement

I am trying to write one if condition in Linux.

I have a variable : `$check_mrp` . I want to check if this variable is not equal to either of the following three values : `WAIT_FOR_LOG` or `APPLYING_LOG` or `WAIT_FOR_GAP` then `echo` message : "Please start the Manged Recovery Process".

For example if variable value is equal to any of the three (`WAIT_FOR_LOG` or `APPLYING_LOG` or `WAIT_FOR_GAP`) then it should not echo the message since services are running.

Comment: Have you searched for "bash conditional if expressions" or anything like that? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression as described in [check if string match a regex in BASH Shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21112809/1983854):

```
[[ $name =~ ^(WAIT_FOR_LOG|APPLYING_LOG|WAIT_FOR_GAP)$ ]]
```

Note the `^` and `$` to indicate that it must be exactly this string.

#### Test

```
$ name="bla"                                                             
$ [[ $name =~ ^(WAIT_FOR_LOG|APPLYING_LOG|WAIT_FOR_GAP)$ ]] && echo "yes"

$ name="WAIT_FOR_LOG"
$ [[ $name =~ ^(WAIT_FOR_LOG|APPLYING_LOG|WAIT_FOR_GAP)$ ]] && echo "yes"
yes
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if [[ ! $check_mrp =~ "WAIT_FOR_LOG|APPLYING_LOG|WAIT_FOR_GAP" ]]; then echo "Please start the Manged Recovery Process"; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ x$check_mrp == x"WAIT_FOR_LOG" ] || [ x$check_mrp == x"APPLYING_LOG" ] || [ x$check_mrp == x"WAIT_FOR_GAP" ]
then
    exit 0
fi

echo "Please start the Manged Recovery Process"
exit 1
```