# Bash rename last underscore in string

Tags: bash, rename

I have got a directory with files in which some of then end with an underscore.

I would like to test each file to see if it ends with an underscore and then strip off the underscore.

I am currently running the following code:

```
for file in *;do
   echo $file;
   if [[  "${file:$length:1}" == "_"   ]];then 
       mv $file  $(echo $file | sed "s/.$//g");
   fi
done
```

But it does not seem to be renaming the files with underscore. For example if i have a file called `all_indoors_` I expect it to give me `all_indoors`.

Comment: Do you just want to remove the underscore, nothing else? Also, where is `$length` defined?

Comment: What do you mean with *strip off*? Remove the underscore, or the underscore and the remaining text?

Comment: @fedorqui Not sure either, think I made a mistake :-)

Comment: strip off. I meant remove the underscore as noted on the example. all_indoors_ should be renamed all_indoors

Comment: @kartoza-geek: yes but say the file is `foo_bar`, should it be renamed to `foobar`, or `foo`?

Comment: if file is foo_bar it should not be renamed. Only when it's foor_bar_ should it be renamed. Hence the need to check the last string if is an underscore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use which will be recursive:

```
while read f; do 
  mv "$f" "${f:0:-1}"; # Remove last character from $f
done < <(find . -type f -name '*_')
```

Comment: This would break if there are newlines in the file names. I suggest to loop over the glob instead of using find here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use built-in [string substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
for file in *_; do
    mv "$file" "${file%_}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a [regex to check the string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21112809/1983854):

```
for file in *
do
   [[ $file =~ "_$" ]] && echo mv "$file" "${file%%_}"
done
```

Once you are sure it works as intended, remove the `echo` so that the `mv` command executes!

---

It may even be cleaner to use `*_` so that the `for` will just loop over the files with a name ending with `_`, as [hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171318/hek2mgl) suggests in comments.

```
for file in *_
do
   echo mv "$file" "${file%%_}"
done
```

Comment: I like this answer, but why not using `for file in *_` ? This would save you the regex check.

Comment: @hek2mgl yours is the most clever approach here : ) I haven't thought about it, updating my answer with it! (Or feel free to add your own answer, of course).

Comment: No, no.. Go for it! :)

Comment: @hek2mgl nice - fedorqui: quote the arguments to move to support files with spaces as in: for i in *\_; do echo mv "$i" "${i%_}"; done

Comment: You probably don't need another `%` (there's no longer match)

Comment: @eugeney But there is also no shorter match! ;) I mean it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Julian yes. Updated to make it more explicit (I couldn't quote again within the `echo` statement)

Comment: You don't have to - prepending the echo in front of the mv as I've shown in my previous comment will work without putting any additional quotes in

Answer (score 0):

Although not a pure `bash` approach, you can use `rename.ul` (written by Larry Wall, the person behind `perl`). Rename is not part of the default linux environment, but is part of `util-linux`.

You use rename with:

```
rename perlexpr files
```

(some flags ommitted).

So you could use:

```
rename 's/_$//' *
```

if you want to remove all characters including and after the underscore.

As @hek2mgl points out, there are multiple `rename` commands (see [here](http://oylenshpeegul.typepad.com/blog/2011/12/a-tale-of-two-renames.html)), so first test if you have picked the right one.

Comment: The `rename` command from util-linux is *not* capable of perl regular expressions! (I also needed to realize that... ;) )

Comment: @hek2mgl: then why does the documentation specifies so?

Comment: If your `man rename` says so, it is not from `util-linux`. What does `rename -V` give you? `rename from util-linux 2.26.2` ? I guess you are referring to http://search.cpan.org/dist/rename/ . Nice tool! But unfortunately not part of `util-linux`.

Comment: @hek2mgl: only `Usage: rename [-v] [-n] [-f] perlexpr [filenames]`. Perhaps I've installed two versions of `rename` fighting with each other...

Comment: To complete the confusion, there also a BSD version available! :) `rename` is a nice tool, but unfortunately it is not portable so far.

Comment: @hek2mgl: well let's agree that in order to remove an underscore, one does not niet *Perlish* powers. (Furthermore I went to FOSDEM last year, and Larry Wall said in his talk that the new Perl regexes would have less representation power, simply because they tend to be error-prone).

Comment: Well, but `rename` from util-linux doesn't support regular expressions at all. It supports only fixed strings. It's really pretty basic.

Comment: @hek2mgl: I've updated the answer with a less ambiguous reference to `rename`.

Comment: If you also remove the sentence that says that Larry Wall's version of `rename` belongs to `util-linux` I'm fine with it. :)