# Using Bash regex match to test membership

Tags: regex, bash

Below, I use ALLOWED as container to test a token. 
I am using a Bash regex match syntax `=~` where the right hand side should be an extended regular expression.

In Bash's Regular Expression Matching. Using the operator =~, the left hand side operand is matched against the extended regular expression (ERE) on the right hand side. Check a related question on using [date regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112707/check-if-a-string-matches-a-regex-in-bash-script).

But I can't see `str1` as a regex and I don't know why `ALLOWED` matches a string which is present inside it.  Even as this works in this case, having regex (str1) as the test string leaves it open for tricky bugs in future.

```
export ALLOWED="str0 str1 strn"
export STR1="str1"
export STR2="str2"

if [[ $ALLOWED =~ ${STR1} ]]; then
    echo "how does it this work?"
fi

if [[ $ALLOWED =~ ${STR2} ]]; then
    :
else
    echo "does not work."
fi
```

Questions:

- Why/ How does this work?
- What's a better to do test for an element in a list in bash?

Comment: I dont' quite understand - what do you observe that you didn't expect? The first regex matches, and the second doesn't, right?

Comment: You example works exactly as expected, what are you trying to do here? The question you ask *What's a better to do test for an element in a list in bash?*, is a different one, bash has a list/array data structure, you can store something in that and then test for membership, using a string for this is a terrible hack.

Comment: I mentioned " I am using a Bash regex match syntax =~ where the right hand side should be an extended regular expression", How is str1 and str2 a regex syntax for ALLOWED?

Comment: `str1` is the literal string `str1` when interpreted as a regex, and that string is contained in `ALLOWED`, so it matches. `str2` is not contained in `ALLOWED`, so it doesn't match.

Comment: It can be wrong if `export STR1="str"` still pass `[[ $ALLOWED =~ ${STR1} ]]; `

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is `content =~ regex`, for example think about how this simple phone number validation works

```
$ phone="555-443-2321"; if [[ $phone =~ [0-9-]+ ]]; then echo PASS; fi
```

as in your example, the right hand side is the regular expression and left hand side is the content.

Your regex can be a string literal, then the check will be whether content contains that substring

```
$ phone="555-443-2321"; if [[ $phone =~ "555" ]]; then echo PASS; fi
```

if it makes it easier for you think that as a regex for `.*555.*`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, the confusion is because `$a =~ $b` checks whether there's a match for `$b` **in** `$a`, not whether `$a` as a whole matches. `[[ "str0 str1 strn" =~ str1 ]]` succeeds because there's a match for the (trivial) regex `str1` somewhere in "str0 str1 strn".

If you want to check for a match to the entire string, you need to anchor the regex with a `^` at the beginning, and `$` at the end: `[[ $ALLOWED =~ ^${STR1}$ ]]`