# Shell REGEX for date

Tags: regex, bash, shell, date

I am trying to fix the users input if they input an incorrect date format that is not (YYYY-MM-DD) but I cant figure it out. Here is what I have:

```
while [ "$startDate" != "^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$" ]
do
  echo "Please retype the start date (YYYY-MM-DD):"
  read startDate
done
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of `!=`, you have to use `! $var =~ regex` to perform [regex comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21112809/1983854):

```
[[ $date =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]]
         ^^
```

So that your script can be like this:

```
date=""
while [[ ! $date =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]]; do
    echo "enter date (YYYY-MM-DD)"
    read $date
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not convert the incorrect format to desired one using date program:

```
$ date -d "06/38/1992" +"%Y-%m-%d"
1992-06-28
```

You can also check for conversion failure by checking return value.

```
$ date -d "06/38/1992" +"%Y-%m-%d"
date: invalid date ‘06/38/1992’

$ [ -z $? ] || echo "Error, failed to parse date"
```