# BASH if 9th character in a line is a specific letter; then

Tags: bash, if-statement

How to perform some steps if the 9th character of a line "$q" is an A, B, C, D, or E. Something like?

```
if [ ${q:9} == [A,B,C,D,E]; then
```

(If the 9th character is a capital A, B, C, D, or E, than do; )

I've used `if [ ${q:9} == A ];` to match one letter, and was trying to construct something like the above or: `if [[ "${p:9}" == "A" && "$p" == "B" && "$p" == "C" "$p" == "D" "$p" == "E"]]; then` to match multiple letters, but does not seem to work regardless of the operator I use.

Comment: Indexing is 0-based; the 9th character of `q` is `${q:8:1}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
if [[ ${q:9:1} =~ [ABCDE] ]]; then
```

`${q:9}` returns all characters from the 9th on (beware, counting starts with 0). `${q:9:1}` returns only one character from the 9th on. The `=~` operator is a "match regex" operator.

Answer (score 2):

use a `case` statement:

```
case ${q:9} in

     [A-E])
     echo found
     ;;

esac
```

Answer (score 2):

Just check the value of the 9th character [with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21112809/1983854):

```
[[ "${var:8:1}" =~ (A|B|C|D|E) ]]
```

For example:

```
$ v=12345678Axx
$ [[ "${v:8:1}" =~ (A|B|C|D) ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
yes
$ v=1234567890
$ [[ "${v:8:1}" =~ (A|B|C|D) ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
no
```

To get the 9th character note I use [Bash Reference Manual → 3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), so the 9th character is `${var:8:1}` because the indexes are 0-based (the first one is the 0<sup>th</sup>):

> ```
> ${parameter:offset:length}
> ```
>
> This is referred to as Substring Expansion. It expands to up to length
>   characters of the value of parameter starting at the character
>   specified by offset. If parameter is ‘@’, an indexed array subscripted
>   by ‘@’ or ‘*’, or an associative array name, the results differ as
>   described below. If length is omitted, it expands to the substring of
>   the value of parameter starting at the character specified by offset
>   and extending to the end of the value. length and offset are
>   arithmetic expressions (see Shell Arithmetic).
>
> If offset evaluates to a number less than zero, the value is used as
>   an offset in characters from the end of the value of parameter. If
>   length evaluates to a number less than zero, it is interpreted as an
>   offset in characters from the end of the value of parameter rather
>   than a number of characters, and the expansion is the characters
>   between offset and that result. Note that a negative offset must be
>   separated from the colon by at least one space to avoid being confused
>   with the ‘:-’ expansion.

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions, you have the option of matching a single character, or a string with an arbitrary 8-character prefix:

```
if [[ ${q:8:1} =~ [ABCDE] ]]; then

if [[ $q =~ ^.{8}[ABCDE] ]]; then
```

You can also use pattern matching, although in this case it looks exactly like a regular expression:

```
if [[ ${q:8:1} == [ABCDE] ]]; then
```