# How to move files en-masse while skipping a few files and directories

Tags: bash, shell, glob

I'm trying to write a shell script that moves all files except for the ones that end with `.sh`  and `.py`. I also don't want to move directories.

This is what I've got so far:

```
cd FILES/user/folder
shopt -s extglob
mv !(*.sh|*.py) MoveFolder/ 2>/dev/null 
shopt -u extglob
```

This moves all files except the ones that contain `.sh` or `.py`, but all directories are moved into `MoveFolder` as well.

I guess I could rename the folders, but other scripts already have those folders assigned for their work, so renaming might give me more trouble. I also could add the folder names but whenever someone else creates a folder, I would have to add its name to the script or it will be moved as well.

How can I improve this script to skip all folders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `find` for this:

```
find -maxdepth 1 \! -type d \! -name "*.py" \! -name "*.sh" -exec mv -t MoveFolder {} +
```

What it does:

- `find`: find things...
- `-maxdepth 1`: that are in the current directory...
- `\! -type d`: and that are not a directory...
- `\! -name "*.py`: and whose name does not end with `.py`...
- `\! -name "*.sh`: and whose name does not end with `.sh`...
- `-exec mv -t MoveFolder {} +`: and move them to directory `MoveFolder`

The `-exec` flag is special: contrary to the the prior flags which were conditions, this one is an action. For each match, the `+` that ends the following command directs `find` to aggregate the file name at the end of the command, at the place marked with `{}`. When all the files are found, `find` executes the resulting command (i.e. `mv -t MoveFolder file1 file2 ... fileN`).

Comment: This one worked. BTW, if i want to add another parameter to the find command i just add a "\ -name" to it?

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man Yes, If it's an exclusion, precede it with `\!` (you can replace `\!` with `-not` with GNU `find`)

Comment: Perhaps you could expand a little on the various switches.

Comment: @xhienne: What do the `{}` and the `+` at the end mean? Actually, that was essentially the only part that confused me :-)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to check every element to see if it is a directory or not, as well as its extension:

```
for f in FILES/user/folder/*
do
   extension="${f##*.}"
   if [ ! -d "$f" ] && [[ ! "$extension" =~ ^(sh|py)$ ]]; then
       mv "$f" MoveFolder
   fi
done
```

Otherwise, you can also use `find -type f` and do some stuff with `maxdepth` and a regexp.

Regexp for the file name based on [Check if a string matches a regex in Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21112809/1983854), extension extracted through the solution to [Extract filename and extension in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/965072/1983854).

Comment: I dont think this one worked.

After i executed the script i got the following error:
cannot move `/FILES/user/folder/' to a subdirectory of itself, `MoveFolder/folder'

Than i added the 2>/dev/null  part but now it doesn`t move anything.

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man I had incorrectly used `-e` to check if it was a file or a dir. Updated to check if it is not a directory.

Comment: It doesn`t show any errors but it also doesn`t move any file into MoveFolder

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man it is weird, it would need some debugging through `echo`s all around. Tested locally it works fine.

Comment: Well i just used echo to show $f and it just prints /FILES/user/folder once

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man I believe you did not add the `*` after `/FILES/user/folder` so that it expands to all the elements in the directory. That is, use `for f in FILES/user/folder/*`.

Comment: Now it reads all files in the directory but it also sends all files except directories, maybe there`s something else missing on the (sh|ph) part

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man ufff I am definitely grateful for your debugging, it wasn't my best fast approach. The error lies on checking the extension, where I was also checking for the dot. Updated.